# StackoverflowException on passing value to another form c#

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

i understand that this below code make a overflow because its called second times.
this is the explanation,
let say i have form1, form2, form3

And in the form1

```
Form NewForm2 = new Form2;
```

And in the form3

```
Form NewForm3 = new Form2;
```

When i showing form2 of course its stack overflow because its called second times on Form1 and Form3,
Okay, so my question is there a way to connect the Form2 from multiple form called it? Any reference?

Comment: You can pass the `NewForm2` reference to the `Form3`, when you create the 3rd form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727986/system-stackoverflowexception-by-forms

Comment: Creating 2 separate instances of a form shouldn't cause a SO. Show your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

*so my question is there a way to connect the Form2 from multiple form called it?*
yes just apply a [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#C_.23) on your form

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

 private static Form2 inst;
 public static Form2  GetForm
 {
   get
    {
     if (inst == null || inst.IsDisposed)
         inst = new Form2();
     return inst;
     }
 }

}
```

to show your form

```
  Form2.GetForm.Show();
```

Comment: available, but i cant passing value to the targeted form (form 2) i mean

Comment: i already figured out,
using this.Close() on the other form to create the new object
thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code to see if `Form2` is already created and if so then show it else create new instance of `Form2`.

```
var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault();

if (form == null)
{
    form = new Form2();
}

form.Show();
```

but opening 2 forms should not cause SO exception, I assume there is a problem elsewhere but you may try code above and see if it fixed your problems.

Comment: yes, the real condition, Form1, is called Form2, Form2 is called Form3 and Form3 is called Form2, this upper answer and you fixed the problem but it cant passing value to targeted form (Form2 i mean)